# calling UIGestureRecognizers targets & actions

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I wrote a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer using the `initWithTarget` constructor as well as `addTarget`, `removeTarget` methods.

Now, my problem is that I am unable to find any accessors or helper methods to call these targets actions.

I believe there should be any List/Array of targets and actions ...

The docs are somehow weak in that particular question.

Thanks for any help,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superclass handles that for you. You just need to set the `state` to the correct value:

```
self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized
```

Please read the [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/GestureSupport/GestureSupport.html) carefully, including the example recognizer there.

Comment: That is just too easy to be true ;-) Thank you.

Comment: If you feel this answer is correct, please mark it as such. Thanks. (Use the checkmark on the left-hand side.)